# How do I submit a Stack Exchange app or get support when the CAPTCHA is broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha, stackapps

I am trying to create a new Stack APP and the human verification CAPTCHA is broken.  Furthermore, when I try to submit a support request, that CAPTCHA is also broken.  I tried to contact Stack on Facebook and Twitter but nobody responded.

the error message is:

> ERROR for site owner:
> Invalid domain for site key

Here are images of the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the kind of bug report a robot would file...

Comment: Looks like a config error on our end specifically affecting stackapps.com only - we'll get it fixed up in a bit here.

Answer (score 7):

As Nick noted in the comments, the captcha wasn't configured correctly for Stack Apps on our end. This has been fixed, so you should be able to submit your app now.

Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the report!